# Using "Return" over "Break" or a combination

Tags: c#, switch-statement

When using the `Switch` statement, is using `return` instead of `break` or a combination of the two considered bad form?

```
while (true)
{
    var operation = Randomness.Next(0, 3);
    switch (operation)
    {
        case 0:
            return result + number;
        case 1:
            if ((result - number) > 0)
            {
                return result - number;
            }
            break;
        case 2:
            return result * number;
        case 3:
            if ((result % number) == 0)
            {
                return result / number;
            }
            break;
    }
}
```

Comment: I would typically use a break even if there is a guaranteed return in case (pun!) a refactor breaks (another pun! I'm on fire!) that assumption.

Comment: @ThomasEding: Visual Studio issues an "unreachable code detected" warning if you do that.

Comment: @RobertHarvey: Interesting. I've never encountered that problem before (or so I believe).

Comment: You can use a combination of both (to an extent) but some IDEs might not be so coorperative with it and long term code maintenance could potentially be a nightmare

Comment: Furthermore, accidental fall-through after refactoring is not an issue in C#, as fall-through is a compiler error. You need an explicit `goto case`.

Comment: I've always tried to stick to the standard that a method should have a singular return vector. Given that standard, a switch should contain only breaks and the method should return the result upon conclusion.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The `break` statement is required in case 1 and case 3.  If you omit it, the code will not compile, because the `if` body is not guaranteed to execute, and fall-through in `switch` statements is not allowed in C#.

The `break` statement is not required in case 0 and case 2, because the `return` always executes; code execution will never reach the `break` statement.  The compiler will issue a warning if you include the `break` statement, but the code will compile.

Not having `break` statements can be useful in simplifying certain mapping or factory functions:

```
public string NumericString(int digit)
{
    switch (digit)
    {
        case 1: return "one";
        case 2: return "two";
        case 3: return "three";
        // ..etc.
    }
}
```

If you need fall-through behavior, you can simulate it with a `goto`, one of the few places in the C# language where using a `goto` actually makes sense, though it's arguable whether or not that constitutes good style.

Comment: `...can be useful in simplifying` was what I was going for. I just don't recall seeing breaks and returns stacked next to each other like I did in cases 1 & 3. I know logically it does what I want. I just thought I went about it in a slightly odd fashion.

Answer (score 5):

I'd avoid using multiple `return` statements in a method like that for the simple reason that you'd need to put a breakpoint on every return statement to see which value is returned (and why).

It'd be better to do something like

```
while (true)
{
    var operation = Randomness.Next(0, 3);
    double? valueToReturn = null;

    switch (operation)
    {
        case 0:
            valueToReturn = result + number;
            break;
        case 1:
            if ((result - number) > 0)
                valueToReturn = result - number;
            break;
        case 2:
            valueToReturn = result * number;
            break;
        case 3:
            if ((result % number) == 0)
                valueToReturn = result / number;
            break;
    }

    if ( valueToReturn.HasValue )
        return valueToReturn.Value;
}
```

For a discussion on having multiple `return` statements in a function, see [this StackOverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/36707/1364007).

Comment: That seems like a really artificial reason to rearrange the code and introduce indirection.

Comment: True, but were the switch statement to get more complex (e.g. more than one screen), it'd be harder to see what was happening with multiple `return` statements. Admittedly, when I say "It'd be better to...", I mean "I prefer to have..." as there's no general consensus on which to do.

Comment: If the switch statement gets *that* big then adding a mutable variable to avoid `return` is just going to complicate things *more*. With a `return` you know for sure you're returning the value; with a mutable variable you have to make sure the code won't either throw an exception or overwrite the mutable variable after the `switch` but before the function returns.

Comment: Does a breakpoint on the closing brace of the function not work for you?

Comment: @Deduplicator - That lets you know that you're returning, but not what value you're returning.

Comment: Hmm - it seems that from VS2013 onwards, you can see the value from the "Autos" window ([link](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/visualstudioalm/archive/2013/06/27/seeing-function-return-values-in-the-debugger-in-visual-studio-2013.aspx)).

Comment: @WaiHaLee good to know for those that have the most current version.

Answer (score 2):

I generally prefer to avoid mixing returns and breaks in switch statements. When I read through code and see a big switch statement, I may want to just skim it quickly to get an idea of what it's doing, then skip over it mentally to read the rest of the logic in the code. If every branch of the switch statement does the same thing, this is easy to do, but if some branches are returning and come are continuing then this becomes more difficult to understand. For this situation, I would prefer a solution like Wai Ha Lee's because it's easier to understand the code quickly.